# Way to avoid running Naturalization application in Germany to be forwarded Berlin

Tags: germany, citizenship, passport

I have recently made a Naturalization application in Germany (1 month ago) in Bayern and am about to Move to Berlin in 2 months, and after I do the anmeldung my application will also be forwarded to the Berlin's office.

This appears quite hopeless to me since in Berlin my request will not be even looked at before the end of this year due to the centeralization of the Einburgerung office in Berlin. Let alone that normal cases also Berlin has a significantly durable process on this topic compared to other cities and can take years instaed of months.

My question is, can you please suggest a few ways to me to keep my application running in Bayern not to be transfered to Berlin? Because otherwise it would be really hopeless...

--Possible ways that I have thought so far is mentioning my place in Berlin as a Zweitwohnsitz, but I doubt I can find a landlord to accept doing the Anmeldung with me in Bayern while I don't live there, and don't know about potential risks. Another option also not doing Anmeldiung for a while...